# Failed at the pkcs11js@1.0.13 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'

Tags: hyperledger-composer, node-gyp

I am getting following error while trying to install hyperledger composer on my ubuntu:

```
60822 verbose stack Error: pkcs11js@1.0.13 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
60822 verbose stack Exit status 1
60822 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> 
(/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:232:16)
60822 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
60822 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
60822 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> 
(/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
60822 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
60822 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
60822 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
60822 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
60825 error Linux 4.13.0-37-generic
60826 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "generator-hyperledger-composer"
60827 error node v4.2.6
60828 error npm  v3.5.2
60829 error code ELIFECYCLE
60830 error pkcs11js@1.0.13 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
60830 error Exit status 1
```

Can someone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was trying to install composer-cli. I was running `sudo npm install -g composer-cli` to install it. So if you're doing the same way (using `sudo`) try to just run the install command without `sudo`. This worked for me on Mac.

Comment: Tried as via both sudo and regular user account. Still fails. I am running Ubuntu server 16.04...